# _append_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[i'm getting this error how to resolve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ3da.png)

I don't know why i'm getting this error

Comment: The message is very clear, you didn't fill the `values` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

np.append function gets 2 arguments. first argument is input array and second one is values. In mentioned problem, you didn't pass the second argument to np.append function.
details in [site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_append.htm)